# Software & Updates and Software Updater doesn't open in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell, update-manager, python3

I don't know exactly what did happen to parts of my system that broke;
I suspect that it's related to my python upgrade but I'm not sure.

Some parts I have already fixed, but it still not opening the `Software & Updates` and `Software Updater` when I click on the icons or even when I try to start it from the terminal.

The output of `sudo update-alternatives --config python3` is:

```
There are 3 choices for the alternative python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3).

  Selection    Path                 Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/python3.9    2         auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/python3.10   1         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.8    2         manual mode
* 3            /usr/bin/python3.9    2         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

I have monitored `sudo journalctl -f` output:

```
fev 15 16:17:55 aorus-15g systemd[3039]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
fev 15 16:17:55 aorus-15g software-properties-gtk.desktop[95441]: Traceback (most recent call last):
fev 15 16:17:55 aorus-15g software-properties-gtk.desktop[95441]:   File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 37, in <module>
fev 15 16:17:55 aorus-15g software-properties-gtk.desktop[95441]:     from softwareproperties.gtk.SoftwarePropertiesGtk import SoftwarePropertiesGtk
fev 15 16:17:55 aorus-15g software-properties-gtk.desktop[95441]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 32, in <module>
fev 15 16:17:55 aorus-15g software-properties-gtk.desktop[95441]:     import dbus
fev 15 16:17:55 aorus-15g software-properties-gtk.desktop[95441]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/__init__.py", line 73, in <module>
fev 15 16:17:55 aorus-15g software-properties-gtk.desktop[95441]:     import dbus.types as types
fev 15 16:17:55 aorus-15g software-properties-gtk.desktop[95441]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/types.py", line 8, in <module>
fev 15 16:17:55 aorus-15g software-properties-gtk.desktop[95441]:     from _dbus_bindings import (
fev 15 16:17:55 aorus-15g software-properties-gtk.desktop[95441]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_dbus_bindings'
fev 15 16:17:55 aorus-15g systemd[3039]: gnome-launched-software-properties-gtk.desktop-95441.scope: Succeeded.
fev 15 16:17:58 aorus-15g systemd[3039]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
fev 15 16:17:58 aorus-15g update-manager.desktop[95444]: Traceback (most recent call last):
fev 15 16:17:58 aorus-15g update-manager.desktop[95444]:   File "/usr/bin/update-manager", line 28, in <module>
fev 15 16:17:58 aorus-15g update-manager.desktop[95444]:     import gi
fev 15 16:17:58 aorus-15g update-manager.desktop[95444]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
fev 15 16:17:58 aorus-15g update-manager.desktop[95444]:     from . import _gi
fev 15 16:17:58 aorus-15g update-manager.desktop[95444]: ImportError: cannot import name '_gi' from partially initialized module 'gi' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py)
fev 15 16:17:58 aorus-15g systemd[3039]: gnome-launched-update-manager.desktop-95444.scope: Succeeded.
```

Any help or reference about how to solve this will be very helpful and appreciated.
Regards,
Leonardo

Comment: Try reinstalling the packages. `sudo apt-get --reinstall install software-properties-gtk.`

This may reinstall the entire system. It could be risky. Be careful

Answer (score 0):

after some days of tests and readings, I did understand what was going wrong;
After I updated my Python version in `update-alternatives` it started to show some bugs and to not open some OS apps;

AS the default python was 3.8 I have changed it back to option 2 of `sudo update-alternatives --config python3` the Software Updater and Software updates started to work as expected.